# Background color on Windows 8.1 live tiles

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a live tile, which I have created in Windows 8.1 using this code. To my knowledge, the background color of said tile is the dominant color of the image. However, my background color is gray and my image is blue. Why?

```
XmlDocument tileData = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Block);
XmlNodeList textData = tileData.GetElementsByTagName("text");
textData[0].InnerText = Math.Round(Double.Parse(data["currently"]["temperature"].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) + "°";
textData[1].InnerText = Math.Round(Double.Parse(data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureMax"].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) + "° / " + Math.Round(Double.Parse(data["daily"]["data"][0]["temperatureMin"].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) + "°"; //Low
TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(tileData);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```

Comment: If it's the done in the same way as the superbar does it for the glow effect on hovered buttons, that would be normal - those get a light blue shade too if the icon has no colors.